# ASP.NET Post Endpoint: Data model in body vs query parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

Making an API responsible for storing files.

The `File` data model looks something like this

```
public class File
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Path { get; set; }
    public string Contents { get; set; }
}
```

So with the post request I setup in my controller (to create the file), I need the `id` of the file, the `path` the file will be stored (relative to a root path I have pre-configured), and the `contents` of the file.

I'm wondering if it's better practice to require a `File` data model to be passed in the body of the request, or to have the `id` and `path` both as query parameters and the `contents` in the body of the request.

Comment: What's the desired behaviour with 2 identical calls, one after the other? E.g store 2 files, overwrite existing, error...

Comment: @sellotape The behavior would be to simply overwrite the existing file. Knowing that, do you think using the data model in the request body, or do you think the combination of query parameters and file contents in the request body is the better option?

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR** - use `PUT /files/{id}` with the content in the body.

What this depends on is - what is the (unique to your system) identity of a `File`?  I'll assume here that it's the `Id` passed in by the client, and that `Path` is simply metadata.  If path forms part of the identity as well, you'll need to adjust this accordingly.

As it's the *client* that supplies and determines the identity, you should probably prefer a [`PUT`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.4) to a `POST`, and supply the identity in the path; e.g. `PUT /files/{id}` with the path and content in the body.  A subsequent identical `PUT` leaves the system in the identical state, so it satisfies the requirement that a `PUT` is idempotent to observers.  A subsequent non-identical `PUT` updates the existing content.

The HTTP spec allows some flexibility here, so you *can* use a `POST`.  The [latest](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.3) has changed the definition of `POST` a little (to have broader application), but in the [original](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-9.5) (emphasis mine)...

> The POST method is used to request that the origin server accept the entity enclosed in the request as a new **subordinate** of the resource identified by the Request-URI in the Request-Line.

... it was clearer that `POST /files` makes sense to create e.g. a file in a directory (their example), but `POST /files/{id}` makes less sense.

[This discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/630453/put-vs-post-in-rest) has some more on PUT vs POST.  It's also asserted there that:

> Note that the following is an error:
>
> ```
> POST /questions/<new_question> HTTP/1.1
> Host: www.example.com/
> ```
>
> If the
> URL is not yet created, you should not be using POST to create it
> while specifying the name. This should result in a 'resource not
> found' error because <new_question> does not exist yet. You should PUT
> the <new_question> resource on the server first.